# How can i simulate just one login for all thread groups?

Tags: jmeter

I have just started working with Jmeter (5.1.1) and i have multiple thread groups.
In every thread group, i have to add the login http request or else the tests will fail.
How can i simulate just one login request for all the thread groups ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) in order to execute the login, setUp Thread Group should be used for preparing test data, if you **really** want to use the same context coming from a single login from all virtual users in all thread groups (this makes sense only if you're using JMeter for a [functional test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_testing)) you can perform the login only once there.

Once you perform the successful login you should pass the associated indicator of the login (most probably it will be [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) or other  [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)) to other Thread Groups, the value(s) can be set using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in the setUp Thread Group and read using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in other Thread Groups